# ABBYY Cloud OCR - How to scan several specific segments at once?

Tags: web-applications, windows-phone-8, ocr, abbyy

I'm working on an application that destined to scan a bill (electricity bill for example) and get the relevant details (amount to pay, user's client number and deadline payment date)
I've downloaded the ABBYY ocr cloud trial and willing to but the full license but having some difficulties regarding the usage .

The documentation seems to advise using : http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/quick-start/text-fields/?utm_source=http://stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=smm
but when working with the demo - I can't find how and where to add the "'region'" field and how can I make it scan several regions at the same time.

I've looked at the code where the language option was defined, but couldn't find the 'region' option - what type should it be ? (Rectangle?)

If anyone worked or works with abbyy I would love to get some help! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our sample for Windows Phone the [processImage](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/apireference/processImage/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=SMM) method is used. It allows to recognize the whole image.

To recognize separate text fields with specified coordinates, you can use the [processTextField](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/apireference/processTextField/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=SMM) method (to recognize one field) or the [processFields](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/apireference/processFields/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=SMM) method (to recognize several fields).

To use the processTextField method, you can change [this line](https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/blob/c8d69e59aec65ac14165bf443a2809a044846512/WindowsPhone/Abbyy.CloudOcrSdk/RestServiceClient.cs#L184?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=SMM) to something like
string url = "http http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/processTextField?region=0,0,200,200&language=english";

The result format is XML.

“Region” is a rectangle. The coordinates of the region are measured in pixels relative to the left top corner of the image and are specified in the following order: left, top, right, bottom.

We recommend to read the Quick Start Guide: [How to Work with Cloud OCR SDK](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/quick-start/work/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=SMM).

Comment: Hey Vitalik, I tried it but it gives me each time one specific place. I want to scan for example two places at the same time, I've tried changing the code of the Demo but I it just won't work. can you please advise how to do it?